# How do I set values for NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject> object in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsdictionary

I need to interface with a function that receives an object of type `NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>` in Xamarin.

First, I don't understand the syntax.
What exactly is a `NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>` type object?
I know there is NSDictionary type and I know how to create one and set keys and values, but what is `NSDictionary<?,?>` ? Is it suppose to be some sort of a special tuple?

Second, how do I create such an object and define the key and associated object?

Answer (score 14):

`NSDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is just a generic version of `NSDictionary`. This means that the keys are all of the type `TKey` (in your case `NSString`) and the values are all of type `TValue` (in your case `NSObject.`). This provides more type safety, because e.g. you can't add integers as keys. The underlying iOS object is still a `NSDictionary`. This class is kind of "syntactic sugar", because we are used to strict typing in C# and want to use it where ever possible.

You can create it with a constructor. It has multiple constructors. E.g. `NSDictionary(TKey[] keys, TValue[] values)` is taking the keys and values as parameters and creates `NSDictionary` of it.

```cs
var keys = new[]
{
    new NSString("key1"),
    new NSString("key2"),
    new NSString("key3"),
    new NSString("key4")
};

var objects = new NSObject[]
{
    // don't have to be strings... can be any NSObject.
    new NSString("object1"),
    new NSString("object1"),
    new NSString("object1"),
    new NSString("object1")
};

var dicionary = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(keys, objects);
```

Answer (score 9):

On Xamarin.Mac, and following Sven-Michael Stübe, it can be:

```
var dictionary = new NSDictionary(
    new NSString("key1"), new NSString("object1"),
    new NSString("key2"), new NSString("object2")
);
```

Probably Xamarin.iOS too but I didn't tested.

Comment: That syntax does work for Xamariin iOS.